# resizing QGLWidget to fit with each sprite size I have

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, scrollbars

I'm creating 2D Map editor using opengl to draw simple 32x32 sprites but it seems that I cannot resize my QGLWidget to a large size (i.e size * sprite size -> 1024 * 32), using 1024 only seems to work fine (using glwidget->setMinimumSize(...)).  I've been googling for a while now about this, the only interesting thing I found is subclassing QAbstractScrollArea and setting my QGLWidget as it's viewport (That's what QGraphicsView does), I also seen all Qt opengl examples but i couldn't find anything that could help (except Image Viewer example which is not exactly what I want), I also tried the following:
`horizontalScrollBar()->setMaximum(width * 32);
verticalScrollBar()->setMaximum(height * 32);`
with the widget resizable set to true/false on the scrollarea but still nothing.
Any ideas how would I do that? I can show more code if you ask me to.

Using Qt v4.7.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two ideas:

If it's possible, drop the idea of using a QGLWidget and place the sprites directly in a graphics scene (QGraphicsPixmapItem). Possibly not what you want, but the graphics scene is made to handle a lot of items, so most things you need (trigger mouse events on items for example) are already implemented.

Or just place the QGLWidget in a graphics scene using a QGraphicsWidget. This should automatically tell the scene its size, which then tells the view the size of the scene. The scroll bars appear automatically if the scene doesn't fit into the view.

**Update:**

As described in [this link](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq26-openglcanvas.html#turbocharginggraphicsview), you can use OpenGL in any graphics view:

```
view.setViewport(new QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers)));
view.setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate);
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help but that's not what I need, I was using that way before and it didn't go as needed. I ran into performance issue with QGraphicsView, low FPS (about 20?)

Comment: Did you try setting the graphics view to use OpenGL? Checkout this: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq26-openglcanvas.html#turbocharginggraphicsview

Comment: I could try that, question though, wouldnt that way lead to the same thing happened last time i was using QGraphicsView? (low FPS etc?)

Comment: Guessing that the low FPS was due to the fact that it rendered the scene in software, the rendering should be far better using a QGLWidget for the viewport. If you don't want to refactor your whole project just to try out, you could do a simple test and compare QGLWidget as viewport (hardware accelerated) versus default viewport (software rendering).

Comment: Thank you, that actually worked good but I still go to test FPS, If i experience issues with it, I'll open a new question.  I don't want to sound dumb but do you think using openGL 2.0+ as described on [link](http://open.gl/) will render faster than using deprecated functions from OpenGL 1.0? (I understand new stuff differ from old ones but I'm newbie to OpenGL).  still reading on 2nd page on that site

Comment: @Fallen Qt uses OpenGL *behind the scenes* in order to paint the stuff you want to be painted. *How* this is done shouldn't be your business, at least not when drawing 2D stuff. So don't worry, Qt tries its best to get a good performance. AFAIK, Qt uses OpenGL 2.0 to draw the graphics scene, but I'm not sure. But I don't think that using a custom render engine based on OpenGL 3 (or whatever) makes it notably faster.

Comment: Failing to editing my previous message, rewriting it again, sorry: yes Qt uses opengl 2 (testing with "QPainter::paintEngine()::type()" outputs Qt::OpenGL2).  I want to use that tutorial to learn from and as a documentation to use when subclassing QGLWidget (I just don't want to use QGraphicsScene to do the rendering for me, cause I tried it before and i'm sure it will be the same thing, what I want to do is, move on and learn new stuff instead of being stuck on auto-call-draw for me)

Comment: Taking a look into QGraphicsWidet, accepting your answer, though.